# How does RPART pick a splitter when there are at least 2 splits having maximal information gain?

Tags: cart, rpart

I'm not sure the best way to explain this, so let me give an example that motivates my question. I have tried reading the RPART manual, documentation, and its code, but I have not been able to resolve this.

Let's build two classification trees from the iris data: one using only 2 predictors (Sepal.Width & Petal.Width), and the other using all predictors. Some things to examine in the code and results below:

- The primary splitters are **different** in each tree
- The cp tables have **different** xerror and xstd values for the first split
- The classification summaries are the **same** (i.e., same class probabilities, elements in each split)
- Manual calculations (*not shown, but can be made available*) show that the primary splitters in each tree have the **same** gini information gain of 0.333

When building out the tree, the algorithm is greedy (and so it doesn't look forward). **If the gini info gains are the same for these primary splitters, how does RPART pick the "winner" to continue building the tree?** I understood that the xerror values come from validation, which occurs *after* the maximal tree is built. Hence, it doesn't make sense to compute xerror when first determining splitters.

**Edit:** Ignoring RPART, how should this situation be handled theoretically? Does it even matter which splitter is picked when they both have maximal information gain?

---

**Code and Results**

(1) Model with Sepal.Width & Petal.Width

```
> iris.rpart2d = rpart(iris$Species ~ iris$Sepal.Width + iris$Petal.Width, data=iris, method="class",)
> iris.rpart2d
n= 150 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 150 100 setosa (0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333)  
  2) iris$Petal.Width< 0.8 50   0 setosa (1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000) *
      3) iris$Petal.Width>=0.8 100  50 versicolor (0.00000000 0.50000000 0.50000000)  
    6) iris$Petal.Width< 1.75 54   5 versicolor (0.00000000 0.90740741 0.09259259) *
        7) iris$Petal.Width>=1.75 46   1 virginica (0.00000000 0.02173913 0.97826087) *
> printcp(iris.rpart2d)

Classification tree:
rpart(formula = iris$Species ~ iris$Sepal.Width + iris$Petal.Width, 
    data = iris, method = "class")

Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] iris$Petal.Width

Root node error: 100/150 = 0.66667

n= 150 

    CP nsplit rel error xerror     xstd
1 0.50      0      1.00   1.12 0.053267
2 0.44      1      0.50   0.58 0.059643
3 0.01      2      0.06   0.07 0.025833
```

(2) Model with all predictors

```
> iris.rpartall = rpart(iris$Species ~ ., data=iris, method="class",)
n= 150 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 150 100 setosa (0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333)  
  2) Petal.Length< 2.45 50   0 setosa (1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000) *
  3) Petal.Length>=2.45 100  50 versicolor (0.00000000 0.50000000 0.50000000)  
    6) Petal.Width< 1.75 54   5 versicolor (0.00000000 0.90740741 0.09259259) *
    7) Petal.Width>=1.75 46   1 virginica (0.00000000 0.02173913 0.97826087) *
> printcp(iris.rpartall)

Classification tree:
rpart(formula = iris$Species ~ ., data = iris, method = "class")

Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] Petal.Length Petal.Width 

Root node error: 100/150 = 0.66667

n= 150 

    CP nsplit rel error xerror     xstd
1 0.50      0      1.00   1.23 0.047053
2 0.44      1      0.50   0.73 0.061215
3 0.01      2      0.06   0.11 0.031927
```

Comment: see this [thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166560/cart-selection-of-best-predictor-for-splitting-when-gains-in-impurity-decrease/166914?noredirect=1#comment316687_166914)